# Is there any way to give money to the hero as a second player henchman?

Tags: fable-2

I'm playing as a second player henchman in Fable II, and I have 34k gold while the other player has 2k or so.  Is there any way for me to transfer some of mine to them?

Answer (score 3):

To just give them the gold, no there is not, but if you go into the options, there is a place where you can slide how much money and/or experience the other player receives (as a percentage). So you would be helping them make gold and not earn any yourself, or very little.

If the slider is set so that one player gets all the gold, anything bought and sold will have all the money go to that player as well, so the income is not just limited to kills.

Comment: Yeah, after we were unable to find a way to transfer money between us ourselves, we changed the gold slider (since me getting money couldn't benefit us in any way).  It is annoying (though perhaps well balanced) that I can't use some of all that money to assist.

Comment: Well you earn money when you're offline from properties, which is the best way I found to get money fairly easy. Save up to buy a few houses, don't play for a few days, log in and collect your rent.  If you wanted to "cheat", you could change your system clock ahead a few years and you'll have all the money you'll ever need! (I never used it, but I heard about it).

Answer (score 1):

Simply have the other person quit: all assets will be transferred to player one, then player two can start again

Comment: Then player two can start again

Comment: you can always edit your posts, there's no need to add a comment that way.